# minusSet function must be case sensitive?

Tags: objective-c

I have two sets of strings that i'd like to get the difference of. Must minusSet function be case sensitive?

How can I improve my check?

Comment: NSSet uses `isEqual:` to check equality. NSStrings will not return YES from this method if the strings they hold are not **exactly** the same. So yes, when you talk about NSString minusSet is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a lowercase version of the set with some KVC magic ;)

```
NSSet *lowerSet = [yourSet valueForKeyPath:@"lowercaseString"];
```

For example: if the original set contains "Alpha", "BETA", "delta" then lowerSet will contain "alpha", "beta", "delta".

A word of caution! Make sure that the set contains *only* strings or you will crash. (actually you are fine with any class that responds to a lowercaseString method)